# Getting ListView Row Index Values

Tags: c#

I am trying to write a piece of code that search a listView for the occurrence of a particular string.

Once the string is found, the code should store the index value of the row where the string was found in the listView.

After compiling the program, an ArgumentOutOfRangeException error occurred on this line:-

store[index] = listView1.SelectedIndices[0];

Could someone please advise me how to resolve this problem...

Thanks in advance

Error Messages:-

An unhandled exception of type 'System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException' occurred in 
System.Windows.Forms.dll

Additional information: InvalidArgument=Value of '0' is not valid for 'index'.

System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException

{"InvalidArgument=Value of '0' is not valid for 'index'.\r\nParameter name: index"}

code:-

```
  private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e){
        int[] store = new int[20]; 
        string s = "    Search Via Forename";
        int result = 0;
        int count = 0;
        int index = 0;

        result = string.Compare(textBox1.Text, s);

        if ((result == 0) || (String.IsNullOrEmpty(textBox1.Text))){
            MessageBox.Show("Please input forename...");
            return;
        }

        foreach (ListViewItem item in listView1.Items){
            foreach (ListViewItem.ListViewSubItem subItem in item.SubItems){
                if (subItem.Text.ToLower().StartsWith(textBox1.Text.ToLower())){
                    count++;
                    statusBar1.Panels[2].Text = "Found: " + count.ToString();
                    store[index] = listView1.SelectedIndices[0];
                    index++;
                }
            }
        }

        for (index = 0; index < count; index++){
            MessageBox.Show(store[index].ToString());
            // MessageBox.Show(listView1.Items[store[index]].SubItems[0].ToString());
        }

        button1.Text = "Clear";
        textBox1.Visible = false;
        button3.Visible = false;
        button2.Visible = false;   

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

For a list use reference instead of index. List are useful because you don't need index to work with them, but you need to keep the reference somewhere or find the object by its value.

Comment: how do you do that?

Comment: When you do {myObject = new Object} you create an instance of it, but myObject only keep the reference to it, not the object itself.

Comment: Let me know if it helped you :)

Comment: So I added the following line ListView listView1 = new ListView(); to the top of my method above  the int[] store = new int[20]; The program executed without any errors. However the program did not find any item indicated by the count variable. If I remove the ListView listView1 = new ListView(); line, it finds the objects search for.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can use your own class based on lisboxitem which can store the font, size, and index and maybe more.

```
Like every item will know his index of course
```

Comment: Please include a code snippet with your answer, otherwise this is a comment at best.